# My batch script keeps writing something in CMD though I only use ping command

Tags: batch-file, windows-server-2003

My problem is that i have created a .bat file which is looking like this

```
@echo off
ping google.com -n 2
if not errorlevel 1 echo %date% %time% We did get a response from Google >> C:\CMD\ping.log
if errorlevel 1 echo %date% %time% We didn't get a response from Google >> C:\CMD\ping.log
```

It's simple and all it does is try ping google.com two times, and if we get a response log "We did get a response from google" else log "we didn't get a response from Google", both with a timestamp to the file ping.log, which is just a text file.

The Batch Script is working when i am using it on my own pc (windows 7), but when i move it the the server then when i click run on the script, it opens up CMD and just keeps writing something over and over again. I don't know exactly what it is writing, but as far as I could spot (because it keeps write in the CMD very fast), is somehting that **@echo off was not reckognized**. When i run the script it doesn't create or write to the files as it's supposed to.

Please anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the file encoding is set to something other than ANSI.

Open your .bat file in Notepad on the server and select File->Save As.

Save it as the same name, but make sure the encoding is set to ANSI.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work now... I think it was also because the folder which it shoudl write to only was read only, but dunno. Thanks though :)